# Font Type similar to Zamenhof Solid

Tags: fonts

can someone please help me identify this font?

[image: Higher Education]

This is found on the [Higher Education](http://www.highereducation.ae/) website.

Someone suggested it is a Zamenhof solid, and while I see the close resemblance (and pardon my non-graphic eye) I still don't see it match a 100% due to spacing between letters etc.

Here is what I have tried:

- WhatTheFont!
- What Font is

These could not recognize the font correctly and redirected me to their respective font forums. the closest answe I received was Zamenhof

This is for a company I am currently working with. They had a designer do this but he's no longer reachable.  I am guessing it is Zamenhof but has been the letters have been pieces together manually vs written out as text - hence the spacing inconsistency.  please help

thanks

Comment: Have you asked the admin/owner of the web page?

Answer (score 0):

I think Zamenhof Solid is right. It looks like they altered it slightly by stretching the letterforms vertically, and yes, you're right, the letter-spacing is very close. But I think it's definitely Zamenhof: the angle of the terminals is very distinctive, and characters like the G are quite distinctive and match Zamenhof Solid.

Comment: Actually I just tried Zamenhof but if you noticed the letter G is not exactly the same with the inner edge of G

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is actually Phosphate RR Solid.
Here's one of the many sources to find this font http://www.azfonts.net/load_font/phosphatesolid.html

[image]

Comment: Could you please back that up with an image of Phosphate RR Solid, and a link to where we can download it? That way, your question and answer are also valuable for someone who visits here later. Thanks!